# Реализовать функцию для кодирования данных, содержащих битовые поля

Tags: python, python-3.x

В решении необходимо использовать побитовые операции. Неиспользуемые поля результата должны содержать нулевые биты.

Входные данные:

Кортеж из битовых полей в порядке от младших бит к старшим. Значения битовых полей имеют тип: целое.

Выходные данные:

Десятичная строка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал:

```
def task7(*d):
    d1 = bin(d[0]) << 4
    d2 = bin(d[1]) << 7
    d3 = bin(d[2]) << 1
    d4 = bin(d[3]) << 8

    r = d1 | d2 | d3 | d4
    return r
```

был бы очень признателен если бы дали ссылки на почитать\посмотреть по теме, потому что почти ничего не понимаю в этом вопросе